# Auto-populate Cell In Excel Based On Contents Of Another Cell

Tags: excel

I am having a hard time grasping coding. My Excel sheet has a cell containing a score. I would like whatever the score is to populate a rating in a different cell:

- 4 or 5 equals Excellent
- 2 or 3 equals Above Average
- 1,0 or -1 equals Average
- -2 or -3 equals Below Average
- -4 or -5 equals Poor

Comment: hint: This is basic use of the `IF()` function, nested. Or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391574/convert-a-range-of-numbers-to-a-letter-in-excel/40391718) may be a more succinct, if possibly less immediately readable, way.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple UDF

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Score(ByVal rng As Range) As String
    If rng.Count > 1 Then
        Score = "Select single cell"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Select Case rng
    Case 4, 5
        Score = "Excellent"
    Case 2, 3
        Score = "Above Average"
    Case 1, 0, -1
        Score = "Average"
    Case -2, -3
        Score = "Below Average"
    Case -4, -5
        Score = "Poor"
    Case Else
        Score = "Unknown"
    End Select
End Function
```

**Example use of UDF in sheet:**

[image: UDF call]

Developer Tab added to ribbon > open with Alt + F11 and add a standard module and place code in that:

**Code in a standard module:**

[image: Code in module]

If you set your data up as a table and enter the formula in the top right hand cell it will auto-populate the formula down all the rows:

[image: Table filldown]

Comment: Any feedback on this please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use nested `IF`s, and a combination of `OR` or `AND` (just user preference really). Observe this nested `IF` formula:

`=IF(OR(A1=-4,A1=-5),"Poor",IF(OR(A1=-2,A1=-3),"Below Average",IF(AND(A1>=-1,A1<=1),"Average",IF(OR(A1=2,A1=3),"Above Average",IF(OR(A1=4,A1=5),"Excellent")))))`

Putting this in `B1` and having it read values off `A1` produces the following (and dragging it down will automatically change it to read off the adjacent cell)

[image: Image1]

Answer (score 0):

With a score in **A1**, in another cell enter:

```
=CHOOSE(A1+6,"Poor","Poor","Below Average","Below Averrage","Average","Average","Average","Above Average","Above Average","Excellent","Excellent")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX({"Poor","Below Averrage","Average","Above Average","Excellent"},MATCH(A1,{-1E+99,-3,-1,2,4}))
```

[image]